# Error when I install Yarn on Ubuntu: "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

To install Yarn, I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv D101F7899D41F3C3
echo "deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

I have Node.js version 6.6.0 installed, yet I get the error:

```
yarn : Depends: nodejs (>= 4.0.0) but 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need Node.js 4.0 or higher to run Yarn. Ubuntu 14.04 only has Node.js 0.10 in its repository, so you'll have to add a different repository to get newer versions of Node. Follow the instructions listed here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But my linux node.js version is V6.6.0, I had updated it to the latest version.(I used this to upgrade my node :[link](https://github.com/tj/n))

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem. You updated node with nvm, but it's not updated in Ubuntu's sources. You need to follow the instructions provided in the link in this answer by running
    `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`
    `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`
    `sudo apt-get clean`